# Android - gradle build for project with 2 source folders fails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

There is open source project https://github.com/PaulVI/freecol-android that I want to add gradle build. It however fails in Gradle 1.12 (and Android Studio 0.8.2) while Eclipse ADT shows it is OK.

Error message example:

```
E:\Android\freecol-android\src\net\sf\freecol\client\FreeColClient.java
Error: (31, 46) Error: package does not exist org.freecolandroid.repackaged.java.awt
```

The packages of course do exist.

[`gradle.build` has](https://github.com/PaulVI/freecol-android/blob/master/build.gradle)

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['j2se-src','src']
```

to define `j2se-src` and `src` as source folders.

Android Studio recognizes 2 source folders, but of course shows the same gradle errors.

[image]

**How to configure Gradle build for project with 2 source folders?**

Answer (score 0):

Closing as silly overlooked java and resource in gradle.build

Should be as

```
        java.srcDirs = ['j2se-src','src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
```